# how to play/pause video in React without external library?

Tags: reactjs

I have a video tag () in my webpage, and a "play/pause" button that when the user clicks on it, the video starts/stops playing . How can I do so in react if I'm not allowed to use js in order to call "getElementById" and then to use play()/pause() build-in methods.
Any idea?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to use `refs` which is a React feature that will let you invoke methods on the component instances that you have returned from a `render()`.

You can read up a little more on them in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

In this case just add a `ref` string to your `video` tag like so:

```
<video ref="vidRef" src="some.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

That way when you add click handlers to your buttons:

```
<button onClick={this.playVideo.bind(this)}>PLAY</button>
```

The `playVideo` method will have access to your video reference through `refs`:

```
playVideo() {
  this.refs.vidRef.play();
}
```

Here is a working [DEMO](https://codepen.io/specialorange/project/editor/DBRddB#) so you can check out a full example.

Comment: Cool. There is any option to call playVideo() from button that is part of other component?

Comment: Yep. You can pass the function references down to any child component through props, as you would any parent-child methods. I updated the demo to use two separate components for the video & the buttons to illustrate.

Comment: yes, but what if both classes (buttons and Video) are children of mutual parent?

Comment: It's generally __very__ good practice to keep a unidirectional data flow in React applications, as it makes situations like this (along with most others) easy to reason about and work with. So my first suggestion would be to consider refactoring. You can still technically do this with `refs` by giving your video component a `ref='videoComponent'` then moving the play/pause to the mutual parent & invoking those methods through `this.refs.videoComponent.refs.vidRef.play() / .pause()`. But as you can see that's starting to get a little crazy.

Comment: This solution works great, but using `refs` this way is now deprecated.

Comment: @BradColthurst I'm not sure I understand the case. Is this it? `<Parent><Video><video/></Video><Buttons><button></Buttons></Parent>` Then, you can `this.vidRef = React.createRef()` in `Parent` component. Pass it to `Video` via props. Attach it to `video` element in `Video`'s `render` method via `ref` attribute. And pass `Parent`'s `onButtonClick` method to `Buttons` component via props, attach it to `button` for `click` event (via `onClick` attr). Then in `Parent`'s `onButtonClick` method we can do `this.vidRef.play()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: And @wogsland probably meant [not using string refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).

Answer (score 38):

Updated example for React Function Components:

```
import React, { useRef} from 'react'

function myComponent(props) {
  const vidRef = useRef(null);
  const handlePlayVideo = () => {
    vidRef.current.play();
  }
  return (
    <video ref={vidRef}>
      <source src={[YOUR_SOURCE]} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Accepted answer was using old react style, if you want to do with  **ES6**

A simple component to auto play pause along with manual controls playing Polestar intro:

```
    import React from "react";
    class Video extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount = () => {
        this.playVideo();
      };

      componentWillUnmount = () => {
          this.pauseVideo();
      };


      playVideo = () => {
        // You can use the play method as normal on your video ref
        this.refs.vidRef.play();
      };

      pauseVideo = () => {
        // Pause as well
        this.refs.vidRef.pause();
      };

      render = () => {
        return (
          <div>
            <video
              ref="vidRef"
              src="https://assets.polestar.com/video/test/polestar-1_09.mp4"
              type="video/mp4"
            />

            <div>
              <button onClick={this.playVideo}>
                Play!
              </button>
              <button onClick={this.pauseVideo}>
                Pause!
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      };
    }

 export default Video;
```

Video from https://www.polestar.com/cars/polestar-1

Answer (score 4):

This answer adds to @mheavers, which I upvoted.

There are a few differences:

- One can pass `noControls` as a prop to the `Video` component, and apply the click event only if the `<video>` doesn't have the default controls *(which will be the case when `noControls` is passed)*.
- The **handler** function is a toggler; enabling one to play or pause according to its current state.
- One can create a play button overlay style through the class `video__play-button`, whilst the same **handler** hides it through the class `is-playing`.
- It also shows how to use two or more `ref` and pass them as a parameter to a pure render function.

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const renderVideo = ({
  noControls,
  src,
  vidButtonRef,
  vidRef,
  handleToggleVideo,
}) => (
  <>
    {noControls ? (
      <div ref={vidButtonRef} className="video video__play-button">
        <video
          ref={vidRef}
          src={src}
          onClick={handleToggleVideo}
        ></video>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <video
        src={src}
        controls
        controlsList="nodownload"
      ></video>
    )}
  </>
);

const Video = props => {
  const vidRef = useRef(null);
  const vidButtonRef = useRef(null);
  const { noControls, src } = props;
  const handlePlay = () => {
    vidRef.current.play();
    // hide overlay play button styles, set by 'video__play-button'
    vidButtonRef.current.classList.add('is-playing');
  };
  const handlePause = () => {
    vidRef.current.pause();
    // show overlay play button styles, set by 'video__play-button'
    vidButtonRef.current.classList.remove('is-playing');
  };
  const handleToggleVideo = () => (vidRef.current.paused ? handlePlay() : handlePause());
  return (
    <>
      {renderVideo({
        noControls,
        src,
        vidButtonRef,
        vidRef,
        handleToggleVideo,
      })}
    </>
  );
};

Video.propTypes = {
  noControls: PropTypes.bool,
  videoUrl: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Video;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const Video = () => {
    const videoRef = useRef();
    const [stop, setStop] = useState(false);

    const handleVideo = () => {
        setStop(!stop);
        if (stop === true) {
            videoRef.current.pause();
        } else {
            videoRef.current.play();
        }
    };

    return (
        <div onClick={handleVideo}>
            <video ref={videoRef} poster={HeroImg} controls>
                <source src={coverVideo} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation. Code only answers are much less helpful to OP or future readers, especially when answering a older question.

Answer (score 1):

Use ref attribute to create a link to the video and using that reference we can able to use video controls on the video component

Try this code,

```
import React from "react";
class VideoDemo extends React.Component {
  
  getVideo = elem => {
    this.video = elem
  }

  playVideo = () => {
    this.video.play()
  };

  pauseVideo = () => {
    this.video.pause();
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <video
          ref={this.getVideo}
          src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />

        <div>
          <button onClick={this.playVideo}>
            Play!
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.pauseVideo}>
            Pause!
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default VideoDemo;
```