# How to play <video></video> in React without external library?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video

I have a video tag in my webpage and a "play/pause" button that when the user clicks on it, the video should start/stop playing. Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work ([how to play/pause video in React without external library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463832/how-to-play-pause-video-in-react-without-external-library)). Is there any chance that there is a conflict with the react-slick carousel(https://react-slick.neostack.com/)?

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

class VideoCarousel extends Component {

    playVideo() {
        this.refs.vidRef.play();
    }

    componentRender(data) {
        const settings = {
            dots: true,
            ...
        };

        return (
          <div id="video-carousel">
            <div>
               <Slider {...settings}>
                  {data.map((item, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>
                         <div className="video">
                            <div className="w-100 h-100">
                               <video className="video-carousel-card-video" ref="vidRef">
                                  <source src={item.video_file} type="video/mp4" />
                               </video>
                               <button className="card-video-button" onClick={this.playVideo.bind(this)}>
                               </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                   ))}
               </Slider>
             </div>
          </div >
        )
    }
}

export default VideoCarousel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on the ref="vidRef". As this is nested to a forEach() function it creates more than one reference to different elements and therefor the play() function doesn't have a specific reference.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed several things:

You should be defining refs for classes like [this example from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) as using `this.refs` is being deprecated:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

You can then defined your play function like so:

```
playVideo() {
        this.myRef.current.play();
    }
```

Secondly, you're missing a `render` function, it is required by all class components.

Lastly, where is `data` coming from? I don't see it defined anywhere, and you're not accessing it via state or props.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-dirac-xo0sj).

Comment: 1. Deprecation has been fixed, 2. Instead of render, I'm using a custom "ComponentRender" function that 3. does fetch the data. Data comes from an API and they render normally. In the code above I removed all unnecessary code. The solution didn't work.

Comment: There is no such thing as a custom render.  React classes invoke the ```render``` function by default.  You can call another function inside of it, but a function named render has to exist.  I don't have enough info to get your code working, but I added a working example in my answer that demonstrates how this can be done.